# ошибка С4703-используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная-указатель "q"

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, циклы, указатели

Дан фрагмент кода:

```c
int A[5]={1,3,-5,4,2}, n=5,*p,*q,a=0,b=0,c=0;
for(p=A+n-1;p>=A;p--)
   if(p>A+1 && p<A+3)
                q=p;
     a=*q; b=*(q-1);
```

задача такая:
Вычислить значения всех переменных в заданном фрагменте программы при выполнении каждой строки.

но когда я пытаюсь запустить отладку, выдает такую ошибку:

С4703-используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная-указатель "q"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Инициализировать `q` вестимо. Об этом же и написано в ошибке. А суть в том, что компилятор не уверен, что в 11 строку попадёт выполнение и следовательно в 12ой произойдёт попытка чтения памяти по неизвестному адресу, что приводит к UB.

Comment: `int A[5]={1,3,-5,4,2}, n=5,*p,*q,a=0,b=0,c=0;` - так лучше не делать [по разным причинам](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvw7k.jpg)

Comment: @user7860670 так что, массивы теперь все?

Comment: @KoVadim речь не а массиве, а о множественных переменных в одной строке. К тому же переменных фактически разного типа.

Comment: вот вот. "фактически разного". и является ли звездочка частью типа очень сильно все меняет. Даже то, куда ее прижимать - к типу или переменной.

Comment: Угадайте типы : `int* A[5]={0} , C[5]={0};` A - это массив указателей на int. С - массив целых чисел. !!! @KoVadim

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я знаю эту особенностью много лет. И в этом как раз и был мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто, вы не инициализировали указатели `p` и `q`

Замените строку инициализации, на такую:

`int A[5]={1,3,-5,4,2}, n=5,*p = nullptr,*q = nullptr,a=0,b=0,c=0;`

Comment: Помогло убрать ошибку, но теперь у меня другой вопрос:
вот задача:
Вычислить значения всех переменных в заданном фрагменте программы при выполнении каждой строки. Для указателей следует указывать номер указуемого элемента массива и значение этого элемента. В цикле значения переменных и указателей следует указывать для каждой итерации цикла.
я просто сделал ```*q=&A[4]``` и при отладке просто записал все значения всех переменных при каждом прохождении цикла
Итак, вопрос:
Правильно ли я сделал судя по условию задачи?